# parse multiple xml file using python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, minidom

I have multiple xml files in a folder. I want to parse all the xml files.I have tried minidom parsing but I could not do it. Here is the xml files are like-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="frame.xsl"?>
<frame cBy="KmG" cDate="03/05/2008 03:50:35 PST Wed" name="Abandonment" ID="2031" xsi:schemaLocation="../schema/frame.xsd" xmlns="http://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <definition>&lt;def-root&gt;An &lt;fex name="Agent"&gt;Agent&lt;/fex&gt; leaves behind a &lt;fex name="Theme"&gt;Theme&lt;/fex&gt; effectively rendering it no longer within their control or of the normal security as one's property. 

&lt;ex&gt;&lt;fex name="Agent"&gt;Carolyn&lt;/fex&gt; &lt;t&gt;abandoned&lt;/t&gt; &lt;fex name="Theme"&gt;her car&lt;/fex&gt; and jumped on a red double decker bus.&lt;/ex&gt;

&lt;ex&gt;Perhaps &lt;fex name="Agent"&gt;he&lt;/fex&gt; &lt;t&gt;left&lt;/t&gt; &lt;fex name="Theme"&gt;the key&lt;/fex&gt; in the ignition&lt;/ex&gt;

&lt;ex&gt;&lt;t&gt;Abandonment&lt;/t&gt; &lt;fex name="Theme"&gt;of a child&lt;/fex&gt; is considered to be a serious crime in many jurisdictions.&lt;/ex&gt; 
</frame>
```

I have tried this below code - where i want to take only the line between ex.

```
from helperDef import *
import os
from xml.dom import minidom

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('frame'):
    for file in files:
        if (file.endswith('.xml')):
             xmldoc = minidom.parse(os.path.join(root, file))
             if '<ex>' in xmldoc:
                line = find_between(xmldoc, '<ex>', '</ex>')
                print(line)
                clean_line = cleanText(line)
                print(clean_line)
```

The error is  -

> TypeError: argument of type 'Document' is not iterable

Any way to do this?Help!

Comment: Can you paste your XML here so that it's easier for others to try?

Comment: I edited my question and add the xml code. @titipata

Answer (score 0):

I think a better to parse xml in python is using xmltodict

you just need to:

```
import xmltodict
```

and then:

```
data = xmltodict.parse(xml)
```

and then your xml file is converted to a python dict which you can work on easily.In your case you can run a loop to convert all files into dicts.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use parse xml files using xml.etree:

```js
from xml.etree import ElementTree

for i in root:
    counter = counter + 1
    for child in root[counter]:
        if child.tag == 'ChildTagName':
            for subchild in child:
                if subchild.tag == 'SubchildTagName':
                    my_VariableName = subchild.text
```